# Angular 5 update field on change

Tags: angular, angular5

In my Angular 5 app I've got two simple variables in my component:

```js
contact: Worker;
wwid: number;
```

And then in the HTML I use the`contact` like so:

```
<worker-lookup [(ngModel)]="contact"></worker-lookup>
```

When that contact model is updated, I then need to assign `contact.wwid` to `this.wwid`.  I'm trying to figure out the "right" way to do this.  I know I could use a getter/setter on the `contact` for example but I don't think that's the angular way.

Comment: (ngModelChange)="wwid = $event.wwid"